# JOIN - Is it a good practice to add table name before column name?

Tags: mysql, performance

In an oracle book I read that when when we perform SELECT by joining 2 or more tables, if tablename is used before the column name SELECT works faster.
Eg:
`SELECT table1.name, table1.dob....` instead of `SELECT name, dob....`

Is it the same way in MySQL?

**EDIT**

I know that this is a good practice when there are identical field names. What i was thinking was about the performance point of view even if there are no identical field names

Comment: sure `explain` gives the same plan

Comment: @triclosan can you explain. i didn't get you fully

Comment: run `explain first_query` and `explain second_query` and compare results

Comment: Thinking logically, it *should* be faster as the RDBMS won't need to inspect each table to find which one contains the desired column; but the cost is pretty negligible - unless you are joining hundreds of tables with thousands of columns each, you'll probably only save yourself a fraction of a millisecond.  That said, I tend to include table qualifiers anyway so that the query is clear and unambiguous to any other human reader.

Comment: @triclosan I didn't know about `explain` syntax. thanks a lot for pointing out to me

Answer (score 1):

I dunno about performance, but it is a good practice, especially when joining tables. Joined tables could have for example identical field names, and the query will then fail. You can also use aliases if your table names are too long:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.dob FROM table1 t1 JOIN table t2 ON ...
```

Comment: This is a good practice when there are identical field names. what i was thinking was about the performance point of view even if there are no identical field names

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I dunno about the performance point of view, but I think the differences are negligible. Have you done some benchmarks?

Answer (score 1):

From the **efficiency** point of view, Oracle and MySQL **compile** the SQL to an internal representation before executing it, so I don't think there must a significant difference in execution time as they will decide the table from the fields name if they are not specified. The time difference will be at compilation time, where they deduce the tables for each field.

In fact, I personally doubt the fact that Oracle executes faster if the table names are specified!

Comment: This is a good practice when there are identical field names. what i was thinking was about the performance point of view even if there are no identical field names

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice when the field names are the same, it's good practice all the time. It's not about efficiency, it's about your query not breaking when someone else adds fields to one of the join'd tables with overlapping names, so your stuff works in six months time, not just today.